# Pandas create df that is the product of columns in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
id | a | b | c | d
------------------
 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5
 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6
```

and I would like to create a new df of which its columns is the difference of successive columns in the first df

new df:

```
id | b-a | c-b | d-c
--------------------
 0 |  2  |  1  |  1 
 1 |  1  |  2  |  1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), for remove first column [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.sub(df.shift(axis=1)).iloc[:, 1:].reset_index()
print (df)
   id    b    c    d
0   0  2.0  1.0  1.0
1   1  1.0  2.0  1.0
```

If need convert to `int`:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.sub(df.shift(axis=1)).iloc[:, 1:].astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  b  c  d
0   0  2  1  1
1   1  1  2  1
```

For changed column names:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
cols = df.columns

df = df.sub(df.shift(axis=1)).iloc[:, 1:].astype(int)
df.columns = cols[1:] + '-' + cols[:-1]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id  b-a  c-b  d-c
0   0    2    1    1
1   1    1    2    1
```

Comment: Thank you! The data in the first option works perfectly, but is there a way to have the column names be a, b, c instead of b, c, d?

Comment: Thank you, this works much better than my initial loop solution  :)

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! It works better, because `sub`a nd `shift` are full vectorized functions. Nice day!